# merging two json result into one and adding the Key inside array?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've merged two JSON response into a single object:

This is how I did it

```
  string peter= "\"peter\"";
  string james= "\"james\"";

var jsonStringJames = await jsonStringJames .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsonStringPeter = await responsePeter.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return Ok("{" + peter+ ":" + jsonStringPeter + ","+ james+ ":" + jsonStringJames + "}");
```

my JSON looks as follow:

```
{
        "peter": {
            "total": 1,
            "result": [
                {
                 "value": "James Bond",
                  "OWNER":"peter" <--- add this
                }
            ]
        },
        "james": {
            "count": 2,
            "next": null,
            "previous": null,
            "results": [{
            "gender": "male"
            "OWNER":"james" <--- add this
            }]
        }
    }
```

How do I add the object name as a key? server-side?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why not deserialize to a data structure and then make whatever changes you need?

Comment: @crashmstr great idea! do you mind sharing a snippet of how you'd do it? thanks!!

Comment: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using ´JObject´

```
var jsonStringPeter = await responsePeter.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objJson = JObject.Parse(jsonStringPeter);
objJson["result"][0]["OWNER"] = "peter";

var jsonStringJames = await jsonStringJames.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objJson2 = JObject.Parse(jsonStringJames);
objJson2["OWNER"] = "james";
```